# Where would I find where an .htaccess file is located and being used on a Mac OS X Lion server that sets Basic Auth on an Apache server?

Tags: osx, apache-httpd, authentication, htaccess

I've installed some software, namely, a continuous integration (CI) server (Jenkins) on a Mac Mini running Lion Server. The server, by default, runs from port 8080 on local host via the url: `http://localhost:8080`. However, when I try to access the page it seems to be protected by Basic Auth and it asks me for a name and a password.

Granted, I never set that Basic Auth and I've been told I can remove the authentication and use that port for the CI server. However, I'm hard pressed to find an `.htaccess` file anywhere that sets the Basic Auth? If it's not set in an `.htaccess` file then where would Basic Auth be set?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the directory `/var/www/jekins`. I'd do a `find /var/www/jekins -name '.htaccess' to locate the file if there is one. If there isn't a`.htaccess` fiel the authentication might be coming from the apache configuration itself.

Did you not create a config file, perhaps `jenkins.conf` under Apache's `conf.d` directory? This is often times under `/etc/httpd/conf.d`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Still haven't found it but I learned a few other things along the way. If I find what's wrong I'll publish the answer.

Comment: @racl101 - the permissions don't have to be done through a `.htaccess` file. They can be done through the httpd.conf or a file under `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*` too. Those are superior ways to do it vs. `.htaccess`.